# Compare time1, time2 in php

Tags: php, time

Hi 
My hardware sends data from a remote site every 2 or 3 second to my website and same is stored in mysql table, the data looks something like this

```
Device_id   para_1   para_2……… date_time  
 044         2223.5     2224.5           2011-02-22  10:20:40
044          2223.5     2224.5           2011-02-22  10:20:41
044          2223.5     2224.5           2011-02-22  10:20:43
044          2223.5     2224.5           2011-02-22  10:20:48
044          2223.5     2224.5           2011-02-22  10:20:49
044          2223.5     2224.5           2011-02-22  10:20:51
044          2223.5     2224.5           2011-02-22  10:20:54
044          2223.5     2224.5           2011-02-22  10:20:56
044          2223.5     2224.5           2011-02-22  10:20:58
.
.
.
.
.
.

044          2223.5     2224.5           2011-02-22  11:21:10
044          2223.5     2224.5           2011-02-22  11:21:12
```

I want to sort my table with date & time column for every 10 minutes. That is starting from beginning I want to store data of every 10th minute to another table. Can anyone help me on how to do this using php script

Comment: Do you want to sample the data, or average it?

Comment: You need to decide what to do with the rows in each ten minute interval. How should they be combined?

Answer (score 0):

The following query will select only entries which happen each ten minutes (at zero seconds):

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE date_time LIKE '%0:00';
```

Comment: i wanted to sample data every 10 mins and store in another table

Comment: That deserves an explaining comment, not a downvote. Anyway, my solution holds: you can do a `INSERT INTO SELECT FROM [...]`, as explained in: http://www.1keydata.com/sql/sqlinsert.html. Regards.